# Setting a Private Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a working example of a `Dictionary<string, int>`. I have a requirement to set the `Dictionary` to a `private Dictionary` and check the value.

Currently I have:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> docTypeValue = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    docTypeValue.Add("OSD", 1);
    docTypeValue.Add("POD", 2);
    docTypeValue.Add("REC", 3);
    docTypeValue.Add("CLAINF", 4);
    docTypeValue.Add("RATE", 5);
    docTypeValue.Add("OTHER", 6);
    docTypeValue.Add("CARINV", 7);
    docTypeValue.Add("PODDET", 8);
    docTypeValue.Add("BOLPO", 9);

    litText.Text = docTypeValue[txtDocType.Text].ToString();
}
```

This works as expected. Would I need to make use of a property? ie below

```
private Dictionary<string, int> DocTypeValue
{
    get;
    set; 
}
```

How can I refactor what I have above to create the suggested `private Dictionary`?

Comment: The requirement seems very technical. If your current solution works, why not use it? And if it does not, what exactly is not working and what would you expect instead?

Comment: `If your current solution works, why not use it?` that's a scary statement

Comment: Select `Dictionary<string, int> docTypeValue = new Dictionary<string, int>();` `ctrl+x` and `ctrl+v` above the method :)

Comment: @Sriram easy enough! Is there a better place to build the `.Add` portion than within the click method?

Comment: @JonHarding Sure, wait a minute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for something like this. Make use of the [Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) feature.

```
private Dictionary<string, int> docTypeValue = new Dictionary<string, int> 
{ 
    { "OSD", 1 },
    {"POD", 2},
    {"REC", 3},
    {"CLAINF", 4},
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want non-members to be able to modify the contents of the dictionary, but want to make it available it is possible to do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<String, Int32> dictionary = ...
public IEnumerable<Int32> Dictionary { get{ return dictionary.Values; } }

// Other methods in the class can still access the 'dictionary' (lowercase).
// But external users can only see 'Dictionary' (uppercase).
void AddItemToDictoinary(String key, Int32 value) {
    dictionary.Add(key, value);  // dictionary is accessible within the class.
}
```

or using an indexer like this:

```
private Dictionary<String, Int32> dictionary = ...
public Int32 this[String key] { get { return dictionary[key]; } }

// Same as above - within the class you can still add items to the dictionary.
void AddItemToDictoinary(String key, Int32 value) {
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
}
```

using the indexer takes advantage of the BST behind `Dictionary<T, U>` (rather than using sequential search). So if you're dictionary is defined like so:

```
class SneakyDictionary { 
    private Dictionary<String, Int32> dictionary = ...
    public Int32 this[String key] { get { return dictionary[key]; } }

    // Same as above - within the class you can still add items to the dictionary.
    void AddItemToDictoinary(String key, Int32 value) {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
public static void Main() {
    SneakyDictionary dictionary = ...
    dictionary.AddItemToDictionary("one", 1);
    dictionary.AddItemToDictionary("two", 2);
    dictionary.AddItemToDictionary("three", 3);

    // Access items in dictionary using indexer:
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary["one"]);
}
```

Comment: I apologize if this is a simple answer, but where is the best place to add the key/values

Comment: Anywhere else within the class. *Class members* still has access to `dictionary`, but outside callers do not. I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of range. If your dictionary is useful for the whole class you could instantiate it a as private static (or not) readonly field with initializer :

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> docTypeValue = new Dictionary<string, int> 
{ 
    { "OSD", 1 },
    {"POD", 2},
    {"REC", 3},
    {"CLAINF", 4},
    // and so on
};
```

But you could also rely on a .Net feature which is called static constructor :

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> docTypeValue;

static YOURCLASSNAME()
{
    docTypeValue = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    docTypeValue.Add("OSD", 1);
   // and so on
}
```

Or a combination of these.

In both cases your dictionary will be initialized once, against your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a private member you don't need a property, just use -

```
private Dictionary<string, int> _docTypeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding about your requirement " I have a requirement to set the Dictionary to a private Dictionary and check the value." you need to have this dictionary on the class level you do not need to create property for the dictionary just create it as a private dictionary.

similar as in the above answer.